# using apache tika for scanning documents on servers using sftp

Tags: python, sftp, apache-tika

I have a tika code in a server. I want to create an SFTP session with another server with files and run Apache tika on that server. I am using python as back end. Will this work ? is my approach correct ?

Thanks

Comment: majorly can i create an sftp session to parse files in different server ?

Comment: What happens if you try? How far do you get? What problems do you face? What errors? etc

Comment: i have just started with creating an sftp session with a server.
For the moment i am grabing files from that server to my server and running tika over those files.

Comment: @LasitPant, Just in case if you didn't consider this option. You can use FUSE to mount content on remote sftp (ssh+ftp)  as a local disk. Here [some howto](http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/), but you can find much more. None of your local programs could recognize that data is taken from another server.

Comment: @rth did knew it . Thanks will give it a try for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I was planning to do was not ideal . .
Apache Tika requires to scan physical files to fetch metadata. I made a bridge and started from sessions pulling files to the server Tika code was hosted.